# should I use smart pointer to insure the memory free

Tags: c++

I did a heap allocation inside a a builder function:

```
bool build() {
   A* a = new A();
   Contener::getInstance()::add(a);
   return true;
}
```

Should I use a smart pointer instead? I am afraid that the object `a` has persisted after the program has stopped.

Comment: yes always. This pattern is called: Resource Acquisition Is Initialization (RAII). In modern OS all process resources are freed implicitly when process terminates.

Comment: You should get in the habit of always using smart pointers wherever you need to use dynamic object allocations. So, in this case, `a` should be wrapped in a smart pointer, yes. If `add()` wants to take ownership of `a`, you can transfer ownership of the smart pointer to `add()`, and then it can transfer ownership again to whatever storage it uses internally. The object will be freed eventually when that storage is done using it. Otherwise, if `add()` does not take ownership, then the smart pointer in `build()` will free the object when `build()` exits.

Comment: Impossible to say. What does the `Contaner` instance do with the pointer?

Comment: Herb Sutter once said: never use "new" again.
Which implies in this case use std::make_unique and std::make_shared which in turn implies use smart pointer whenever you don't have a good reason to do otherwise.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE&ab_channel=CppCon

Comment: If in doubt, you may be able to decorate your `A` destructor, like in `~A() { std::cout << "A dtor\n"; }`, run your program, and check if `a` is properly destroyed.

Comment: Use `A*` (*raw pointer*) or `A&` (*reference*) as a parameter or result when **not** passing ownership.  Using `std::unique_ptr<A>` as a parameter or result when passing ownership.  Search for **Herb Sutter unique_ptr Guru of the Week** for some of his GotW articles on the subject.

Comment: When in doubt, prefer to use smart pointers. But the devil is always in the detail. The question is who is the owner (the owner decides when it is the memory is released). Do you have appropriate ownership semantics defined for the memory (i.e. Is it always clear who owns the memory)? Smart pointers will help in this regard but are not the only way to do this.

Comment: for detail `Contener::getInstance()::add(a)` will add a to a list of pointer inside Contener --> ownership --> I should use unique_ptr<A>

Answer (score 0):

The memory allocated for your `A` will be released to the OS when your program exits. However, the object `A` may contain resources that require some cleanup, and for that reason you should always clean up after yourself (as Marek already commented).

Also, it is a good habit to have :)